# Spring Integration HTTP: inconsistent attribute "path" for element "inbound-gateway"

Tags: spring-integration

I noticed that Spring Integration use an attribute "path" in the element "inbound-gateway", as reported in the documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#_request_mapping_support

But in the XSD of HTTP Integration the "path" attribute doesn't exist:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd

<xsd:element name="inbound-gateway">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Defines an inbound HTTP-based Messaging Gateway.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="gatewayType">
                <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="extract-reply-payload" type="xsd:string" default="true"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="supported-methods" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="view" type="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo>
                            <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                                <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.web.servlet.View"/>
                            </tool:annotation>
                        </xsd:appinfo>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:attribute>
                <xsd:attribute name="request-mapper" type="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:annotation>
                        <xsd:appinfo>
                            <tool:annotation kind="ref">
                                <tool:expected-type type="org.springframework.integration.http.InboundRequestMapper"/>
                            </tool:annotation>
                        </xsd:appinfo>
                    </xsd:annotation>
                </xsd:attribute>
                <xsd:attribute name="request-key" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="reply-key" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:attribute name="reply-timeout" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This seems to be the list of the "accepted" attributes:

```
name
extract-reply-payload
supported-methods
view
request-mapper
request-key
reply-key
reply-timeout
```

The "path" attribute doesn't exist in the definition.

The effect is that I have an error at the start of the application:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 71; columnNumber: 53; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute "path" is not allowed to appear in element "int-http:inbound-gateway".
```

This is the "incriminated" portion of the configuration:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                      path="/receiveGateway"
                      supported-methods="POST"/>
```

This is inconsistent!
Maybe something is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to search through the Internet from which Spring Integration version you are showing that XSD, but that is really enough old and there is definitely present `path` attribute in the current and many previous versions:

```
<xsd:attributeGroup name="inboundCommonAttributes">
    <xsd:attribute name="path" type="xsd:string">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Comma-separated URI paths (e.g., /orderId/{order}).
                Ant-style path patterns are also supported (e.g. /myPath/*.do).
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

Please, consider, switch on Spring Nature in your Eclipse to let it to read XSDs from the jar in project rather than from the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

It usually happens when you haven't put enough dependencies in your pom.xml.
So the answer to this specific problem is to add the following code

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-http</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

then your compiler won't validate your xml with online xsd, instead ,it will validate with local xsd which is hidden in the dependency jar you have just added.